# Project Lombok in Oomph Installation Profile

Tags: eclipse, lombok, oomph

Is it possible to integrate Project Lombok (https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) into an Oomph (https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) Installation Profile?

In the installation guide of Lombok, it is only described, how to install it manually, but we would like to integrate the lombok installation in our projects oomph profile.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried if it works, but I see the following steps to be performed:

1. The OOMPH setup has to be extended to add a line like follows to the eclipse.ini:
   `-javaagent:/.../eclipse/lombok.jar`
2. The OOMPH setup has to somehow download/checkout the lombok.jar from somewhere.

whereas the first step can be configured with the EclipseIniTask as follows:

```
  <setupTask
  xsi:type="setup:EclipseIniTask"
  option="javaagent"
  value="${installation.location|uri}/lombok.jar"
  vm="true"/>
```

and the second step - with help of ResourceCopyTask:

```
<setupTask
    xsi:type="setup:ResourceCopyTask"
    sourceURL="https://some-sever.com/lombok.jar"
    targetURL="${installation.location|uri}/lombok.jar"/>
```